# How to use a value in previous line

Tags: php, html, css

I know this is a weird question and maybe there are better solutions but in this step of my project it difficult to reform project.

I have some pairs of tags in my html similar to this:

```
<div>
    <label for="first">text</label>
    <input id="first" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="second">text</label>
    <someTag></someTag>
    <input id="second" />
</div>
```

I intend to generate this html with php, some thing like this code:

```
<?php
    $form = new htmlform('formname');

    echo $form->label('text');
    echo $form->input('first');

    echo $form->label('text');
    echo $form->input('first');
?>
```

here is the problem...

as you see I type `input id` in second line but labels need that `id` too.

how can I put text in `second` line and use that in `first` line?

any byref or some thing.?.

Comment: we need to see the code inside `$form->input()` and `$form->label()` too

Comment: I simply print tag like: echo "<input id='$name' />";

Comment: Does it make a difference if I tell you that this has the same visual output as the contents of your first div? `<label>text<input id='first"/></label>` I.e - is there any reason to create a label that refers to an element, when you can simply wrap the element with a label?

Comment: yes, but some inputs and labels are not close to each other in html..

Comment: I'm not understanding at all what you want to do. Are you looking for a dynamic form handling or what?

Comment: Do you want to be able to print a form like such dynamically? : http://prntscr.com/4c04d3

Comment: yeah some thing like that...

Comment: What I mean is: what is **exactly** the problem above? do you need a function that prints an input and its label that eventually accepts some other content to print **between** the input and the label? is that what you need? please provide us **what's the result you expect**, I've made a little class to do that, but I'm not sure if that's what you want because I'm not understanding the problem here :P

Comment: Is this what you want to see? : http://prntscr.com/4c09ac I mean, do you need these three cases?

Answer (score 0):

Can you consider some

```
labeled_input(id, text)
```

that generates both, the label and the input?